# WPF show image problem

Tags: wpf, image

I have a problem showing a simple image in WPF:

There is a web service which returns a byte array.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(barrImg);

FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\\temp\\text.jpg", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
fs.Write(barrImg, 0, barrImg.Length);
fs.Flush();
fs.Close();
```

for test purposes I write the array to a file - no problem viewing this picture!

Then I put the image from the file into an property of the class for transfer, as shown in many other explanations:

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.BeginInit();
bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(@"c:\\temp\\text.jpg");
bitmap.EndInit();
imageFromDatabase = new Image();
imageFromDatabase.Source = bitmap;
```

The property is defined as follows:

```
private Image _imageFromDatabase;
public Image imageFromDatabase
{
   get { return _imageFromDatabase; }
   set
   {
      _imageFromDatabase = value;
   }
}
```

In the display class I have the following (the filling of the property is executed elsewhere and works):

```
picture1 = wsh.imageFromDatabase;
picture1.Height = double.NaN;
picture1.Refresh();
```

But, nothing is shown in the picture.

The xaml file shows

```
<Image Height="100" Name="picture1" Stretch="Fill" Width="Auto" />
```

for the picture1 element.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Axel

Comment: Was there a specific reason to set `picture1.Height` to `double.NaN`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the `Source` property?

```
picture1.Source = wsh.imageFromDatabase.Source;
```